# RAID-0 bottlenecking when reading and writing simultaneously?

Tags: ssd, raid, raid-0, hardware-raid

I have 4 Samsung 840 Pro SSDs running in hardware RAID on an Intel RS2BL080 LSI RAID card. My read and write times are incredible:

```
$ dd bs=1M count=10000 if=/dev/zero of=test.img conv=fdatasync 
10000+0 records in 
10000+0 records out 10485760000 bytes (10 GB) copied, 6.3633 s, 1.6 GB/s
```

Read times are at about 2.0GB/s.

However, when I try duplicating a local file, I'll see my write speed drop to around 200MB/s. What could be going wrong here?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/6RQX3ub8) is my RAID card configuration, perhaps I misconfigured something? Any one of these drives can get >450MB/s write speed, I've seen it before while not using RAID.

### Update

Interestingly enough, I've found that some of these limitations have to do with the filesystem. `ext4` starts out fast and slows down to a rate of about 230MB/s. `btrfs` however, only slowed to about 830MB/s. `ntfs` was slow like `ext4`. Are there configuration options for `ext4` to speed it up?

Comment: What is the mount option for ext4? Maybe post your `/etc/fstab`.